# Exporting just the html table in a classic asp page

Tags: asp-classic, export-to-excel

we had some demands here in my job that include working with asp.
We are not experient with that and I could not find a solution to this problem in the other topics here in stackoverflow

the thing is, if I put

```
<%  Option Explicit
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=excelTest.xls"
%>
```

the whole page goes to the excel file.

and I want only one table to be in the generated xls file.

the table I want is beeing generated by this line:

```
<% =Result %>
```

how can that be achieved?

thxxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need something in your URL that makes the request for the XLS version distinct from the standard version.

Typically you do this with a query string value so your URL becomes  `http://yoursite.com/yourpage.asp?mode=xls`.

Now in your code you can use:

```
<%
Option Explict
Dim result

''# Build Table into result variable

If Request.QueryString("mode") = "xls" Then 
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"    
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=excelTest.xls" 
Else
%>
<html>
    <!-- Normal HTML before the table here -->
<%
End If

Response.Write result

If Request.QueryString("mode") <> "xls" Then
%>
    <!-- Normal HTML after the table -->
</html>
<%
End If
%>
```

In you include in your page a line back to itself with the extra `?mode=xls` on the end the user will get excel launched with just the table loaded into it.

Comment: We have tried that but th whole page kept beeing saved...
So I solution I found was to pass this table to another page and inside this page I had the Response.Content type and other stuff.
Thx for the help =)